# Spark 2.2.1 HQL to ALTER Hive Table with partitions fails with InvalidOperationExeception

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I have an application where I'm sending HQL using `SparkSession.sql()` method.

First I create a table with parititions

`CREATE TABLE table_name (Id BigInt) PARTITIONED BY(Age BigInt)`

After this I have following `ALTER` table statement as follows :

`ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMNS(Name String)`

The `ALTER` command is failing with following exception :

```
InvalidOpearationException(message: parititions keys can not be changed)
```

When I try to execute ALTER statement on a table which doesn't have any partitions it runs fine.

Also the above code runs fine with **Spark 1.6.**

The above HQL statements also works fine if I directly run them in Hive.

I read the change log of Spark but couldn't find any explanation for following behavior.

Can anyone help me in figuring out what is happening ?